Clone movie with a clone that is living another mans life.
I remember watching a movie when I was little so the release year would probably be between 1995 and 2001. 
The plot is a guy is a clone of a dad of a family but the family doesn't know it. 
One scene is where the clone watched a home video of the real dad and family singing a song so the clone sings it while they are driving. 
In another scene, either the daughter or son has a gun and is going to shoot the clone and the clone is wearing the wedding ring and that's all I remember. 

I believe I am looking for the same movie, but cant remember the name. It was a scientist whom in an experiment made seven clones. One of the clone started to kill the other clones, and eventually he would try to kill the last clone which had a "perfect life". I believe the name of the evil seventh clone was "Simon" and he had one particular feature on him that the other clones would not have, in which it was possible to distinct him from the other clones (a birthmark of some sort).

Sounds like Mr. Murder from 1998 with Stephen Baldwin, based on the Dean Koontz novel.

A group of scientists are trying to produce the perfect soldier by cloning. The day the clone is born, Marty Stillwater, a mystery novel writer, feels that something strange is going on inside his body and mind. Seven years later, Marty discovers that his double has his same physical appearance but has the personality of a murderer.

There's a connection between them and the clone eventually wants to take over Marty's life and family. IIRC, both of the plot points you mentioned (the song and wedding ring) are there. Here's the trailer:




The Sixth Day? 2000
Here's the plot from Wikipedia:

"A world of the very near future in which cattle, fish and even family pet can be cloned. But cloning humans is illegal -- that is until family man Adam Gibson comes home from work one day to find a clone has replaced him. Taken from his family and plunged into a sinister world he doesn't understand, Gibson must not only save himself from the assassins who must now destroy him to protect their secret, but uncover who and what is behind the horrible things happening to him." -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_6th_Day


Considering the family in 6th day wasn't involved, I'd say no. Neither the singing part, or the kids holding a gun happen.

@cde - the family wasn't involved?  You need to re-watch that movie.  Arnold, watching in horror as his clone interacts with his family (and, I think, especially with his wife) is a huge part of that movie. Not to say I remember a scene with a gun, but there was family involved.
